# SVG elements disappear after dynamic updates in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This issue does not affect Chrome, but is consistent in Edge and Internet Explorer.

I have two svg's defined in my .cshtml:

```
<div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
<div class="col-sm-1" style="height:inherit;">
    <div class="card" style="height:100%">
        <svg id="bayLegendSVG" viewBox="0 0 112 900" height="100%" width="100%" style="display:block; margin: auto;">
            <g>
                <g name="Empty" style="display:none">
                    <text x="56" y="256" text-anchor="middle">Not Selected</text>
                    <circle class="zoom" cx="56" cy="300" r="31" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="12" fill="white"></circle>
                    <text name="count" x="56" y="305" text-anchor="middle">81</text>
                </g>
                <g name="Selected" style="display:none">
                    <text x="56" y="556" text-anchor="middle">Selected</text>
                    <circle class="zoom" cx="56" cy="600" r="31" stroke="orange" stroke-width="12" fill="white"></circle>
                    <text name="count" x="56" y="605" text-anchor="middle">0</text>
                </g>                    
            </g>
            <additional g's...>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7" style="height: inherit;">
    <div class="card" style="height:100%;">
        <svg id="baySVG" viewBox="0 0 788 900" height="100%" width="100%" style="display:block; margin: auto;" >
            <g name="bayText">
                <circle cx="384" cy="6200" r="6170" stroke="darkgrey" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
                <text x="353" y="20">Top Label</text>
            </g>
            <g name="bayText">
                <circle cx="384" cy="6200" r="5340" stroke="darkgrey" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
                <text x="334" y="885">Bottom Label</text>
            </g>
            <lots of additional g's...>
        </svg>
</div>
<div>
```

I am making changes to these elements from JavaScript (showing/hiding certain elements, changing colors, changing text, etc.) based on user selections.

The issue is that some or all of the elements in the SVG will not be displayed after user interactions, even interactions that do not initiate dynamic changes to elements. The html for the svg is there, and it is not set to hidden (proof is that it always works in Chrome). And to make everything appear as intended, all that I need to do is resize the browser **or even just click anywhere on the SVG** (everything immediately appears).

I am fairly new to svg's and love everything they have provided...except for this.

Edit: The issue seems to occur when the height of the page changes (from either hiding or showing divs to the right of the content I have posted). It does not change the height of the SVGs, as thy are set when the page is created. The area to the right changes and is scrollable.

I am wondering if it has something to do with using the collapse hide/show and there being some issue with animation happening after the SVG content has been updated.

Comment: Is there a stylesheet applied to your page? Please edit your post and show all rules for the divs and `<svg>` elements. (And one for the road: `height` is not inheritable.)

Comment: I don't have any problem seeing it in edge after removing `style="display:none"` . Also, after removing `style="display:none"` you may need to scroll a lot in order to see anything.

Comment: @enxaneta I do not have a problem seeing it either on the initial load. But when I the user interacts with content on the right-side of the page (which changes both the SVG content and the cards and divs to the right), I am losing some SVG content.

Comment: In this case you need to update your code with *the content on the right-side of the page* and it's functionality

Answer (score -3):

Sorry but edge / internet explorer is not a good browser he not support few class css/svg.. is normal , use chrome.